# IF statement with three conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]

column V is homework actual finish date
column W is required finish date

> condition 1: if V is not blank, return value "ok"
>   condition 2: if "V is blank" and "W is blank", return value "ok"
>   condition 3: if "V is blank" and "W>=today()", return value "overdue"

I'm only able to combine condition 1 and 3 in my IF formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(V2)),"ok",IF(W2<=TODAY(),"over due","ok"))
```

Could anybody help me add condition two into my formula?

thanks for everybody's help/ im really new to stackoverflow.
and i have already learned something from everybody.

btw i made a typo in my condition 3, it should be "W<=today()" instead "W>=today()"

thanks

Comment: Have you tried building helper columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=if(  and(  not(isblank(v2)), not(isblank(w2))  ), "ok",
    if(  not(isblank(v2)), "ok",
       if(  and(  isblank(v2),  w2 >= today()  ), "overdue", "ok"  )
    )
 )
```

Paste this directly into the formula box and see how it works.

Comment: =if(  and(  isblank(v2), isblank(w2)  ), "ok",
    if(  not(isblank(v2)), "ok",
       if(  and(  isblank(v2),  w2 <= today()  ), "overdue", "ok"  )
    )
 )      I have changed the formula as shown above and it worked. thanks for the help.

Comment: You are most welcome! To bring closure to your question, feel free to mark any of the answers above as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see;

Your decision tree is missing one possible output; when V is blank, W !is blank and W<=today()

once you tell us what output means to you, we can easily help you.

Comment: Valid comment, but not an answer. I see your reputation would prevent you from commenting - please ensure you edit your answer once the OP has provided clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(V2)),"ok",IF(ISBLANK(W2), "ok",IF(AND(ISBLANK(V2),W2 >= TODAY()),"Over Due", "Error")))
```

As tip for future macros, try building them up a little at a time. For IF statements it can get tricky but this may help.

Write the first condition like this with 'Other Value' as a place holder.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(V2)),"ok","Other Value")
```

Once you have that bit working the way you like it then put in the false condition like this.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(V2)),"ok",IF(ISBLANK(W2),"ok","Other Value"))
```

And then finally add your last condition.

Comment: Good tip on building functions one section at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with one AND statement. First, redefine the logic you need for yourself: there are only two outcomes you care about: an assignment is unfinished and overdue, OR an assignment is finished/not yet due. So to write our IF statement, check only whether the assignment is unifinished and overdue. In any other case, the status will be the same.

*Edit per comment*

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(V1),W1<=TODAY(),W1>1),"overdue","ok")
```

Comment: You might want to redefine it again. Both blank = overdue?

Comment: Agreed, thanks - missed that the due date was not always filled out; added another term to the AND statement.

Comment: @JMIZE Please clarify your definition of OVERDUE because this answer's defines it the opposite of how your question does. All the other answers followed your definition.